# How do I copy HTML script tag to external javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

I received HTML script from Kakao maps API to use map on my Gatsby(React) website. However, React doesn't allow me to directly copy the following script to index.js render(). So I'm thinking of making external App.js to run this code:

```
<script src="//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=MYAPIKEY"></script>
<script>
    var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOption = {
            center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56682, 126.97865),
            level: 3,
            mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }; 

    var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption); 

</script>
```

How do I write the following script tag to javascript? I think the second script just need to copy the lines between , but I'm not sure about the first script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file named `gatsby-ssr.js` in the root of your project and use the `setHeadComponents` function from the `onRenderBody` API to add scripts to the head of HTML:

```
exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
  return setHeadComponents([
    <script src="//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=MYAPIKEY"/>,
    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOption = {
          center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56682, 126.97865),
          level: 3,
          mapTypeId: kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };
      var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption);
      `,
      }}
    />,
  ]);
};
```

Read more about its usage in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/#onRenderBody)